# how to open google map app by clicking on a hyperlink

Tags: php, android, google-maps, hyperlink

I have made an WebView android application.
And on a website i have given a link MAP where user clicks and it will take to the google map.

I want that if a user clicks on MAP link from the android application or website so the google MAPS application GPS live address tracking which will open outside the application not the site inside the android app.

I am using the code below:

```
<a  
href="http://maps.google.com/?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=<?php echo $eAddr; ?>&z=17"
>Show Map</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can implement the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)

and do something like

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

...

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(uri.startsWith("http://maps.google.com")) {
          Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
          startActivity(intent);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Don't have a chance to test now, but it should work in theory

Good luck